# My passport has expired and I forgot about it. What about my EU Blue Card?

Tags: germany

I currently live in Germany, working under a blue card. My situation is this:

Under my blue card is written:

> 19A AUFENTHG IVM 2ABS 1 NR 2A BESCHV
>   SIEHE ZUSATBLATT PASS-NR XXXXX
>   GULTIG BIS 23.06.2018
>   KARTEBNUTZUNG BIS 23.06.2018

My passport expired on 23.06.2018 and apparently my blue card too. I honestly forgot about that, in my head my passport was valid until 2019.

What are the risks here? I'm going to request a new passport tomorrow, which will arrive August 15. Am I in an illegal situation? I have an appointment for the *Ausländerbehörde* and plan to go there once I have my passport.

Can I travel outside Germany even with this blue card situation?

Can I continue to work under that? I'm also switching companies right now and I'm not sure about the legal implications.

Comment: You must go to Ausländerbehörde as soon as possible and explain the situation. Don't wait until you get your passport.

Comment: @ExPatriot That is an answer, not a comment.  Please don't put answers in comments.

Comment: @MartinBonner How is it an answer? There are five questions asked and my comment does not answer any of them :)

Comment: @ExPatriot So it's not a *complete* answer, but it is an answer to the (implied) question "what should I do?", and it is certainly not a request for more information, or a suggestion to improve the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I called the Ausländerbehörde and what happens is that my residence permit is still valid, just my card is associated to an expired passport. So i need to issue a new passport and issue a new blue card.

But even before i have the new blue card i can still travel, work or anything else cause my residence permit is valid.

Here is the reference:
https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/326798/

Comment: Fantastic!  My experience too is that the Auslandamt of my local Kreis is very friendly.

Comment: You may be able to trav,el as far as Germany is concerned, but without a valid passport you probably have nowhere to travel *to.*

Comment: I mean travel after i have a valid passport again ofc. You can't leave germany without a passport but that's kind of obvious i guess.

Comment: Uh, of course you can. There are no border checks within the Schengen zone. You just shouldn't.

Answer (score -2):

Technically you are now illegally in Germany - you have no valid passport, you have no valid residence permit. This means that it's better for you not to travel anywhere - someone wants to check your papers and you get problems.

You must go to the Ausländerbehörde as soon as possible and if you're lucky and the clerk is lenient you'll hopefully get a *Fiktionsbescheinigung* which would prove your legal residence in Germany until you get a new Blue Card or residence permit.